# Ruby Quotes Syntax when using Mandrill

Tags: ruby, string, smtp, mandrill, mailer

I have a Ruby on Rails app and I am writing my mailer to send SMTP headers to Mandrill.
I think I have an issue with getting a variable into a string:

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer

helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`

def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

     headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = '{"ctoken1": "Drip Email"}'

     temp_var = "Hello Everyone"
     headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = '{"tag_test_1": "yoyoyo"}'           # 1

    # headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = "{'tag_test_1': 'yoyoyo'}"          # 2
    # headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = "{'tag_test_1': #{temp_var}}"       # 3
    #  headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = '{"tag_test_1": #{temp_var}}'      # 4

     headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = '{"ctoken3": "Test at the End"}'

     super

end

end
```

I want to get the "temp_var" variable into the header.  You can see my 4 attempts.

Firstly - a sanity check - The syntax in #1 works fine - the variable "tag_test_1" in my mandrill email gets replaced by "yoyoyo" but of course this is not using a ruby variable.

None of my attempts 2,3 or 4 work.  My Mandrill email receives TAG_TEST_1 rather than the variable replacement ("Hello Everyone").

Ultimately what I am trying to do is get the Account Activation link into an email via Mandrill.  So I think I will need to send the 'token' variable, but for now I cannot seem to get a known variable (temp_var) to get passed to the email.

My suspicion is that I am not understanding the Ruby string syntax correctly.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = "{\"tag_test_1\": \"#{temp_var}\"}"
```

Or this:

```
headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = %Q'{"tag_test_1": "#{temp_var}"}'
```

Comment: Fantastic spickermann - and what a ridiculously fast response! Thanks a lot - this worked perfectly.  I guess I needed to escape the quote characters - I can't fully get my head around why I needed it, but I can now move on.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's important to note that you cannot use the #{} syntax within single quotes. You can only use that within double quotes. Also note that when you use the new hash syntax `{'': ''}` it will convert the string to a symbol. The answer above should work.